# Is this correct statement to check the duplicate values?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following fields:

```
domainname | domian_name_cert_no | keyvalue
```

The `domian_name_cert_no` is unique and it ends with a counter; 1,2,3 etc. There is a possibility that two or more `domian_name_cert_no` share the `keyvalue`. I need to list these cases. So I have the following statement to list the occurrence of `keyvalue` in the first `domian_name_cert_no`  (i.e, no =1 only. I don't care about duplicates in _2,_3).

```
select domainname, domian_name_cert_no, count(keyvalue), keyvalue 
from db.table 
where domian_name_cert_no like '%_1'
group by (keyvalue) 
having count(keyvalue)>1;
```

Assume the one output like:
xyx , xyx_1 , 10 , 777

Then, based on the previous output I know there are 10 occurrence, Now I need to list these domain names which have shared `keyvalue` in detail, so I used:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    db.table a
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT keyvalue
                FROM db.table
                GROUP by keyvalue
                HAVING COUNT(keyvalue) = 10
            ) b 
                ON a.keyvalue = b.keyvalue;
```

Are these correct statements based on my explanation for the need ? I'm not really sure for what I did in the second statement in: `HAVING COUNT(keyvalue) = 10`.

MySQL experts, please, confirm to me if the statements are correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Changed per OP additional comments**

Your first query doesn't look quite right.

```
select keyvalue, count(domian_name_cert_no) as rec_count 
from db.table 
where domian_name_cert_no like '%_1'
group by keyvalue 
having rec_count>1;
```

For your second query, I'm not sure what you are trying.  My best guess is that you want to get all the records having the keyvalues you identified in your first query.  Just insert your first query into the inner join.  You won't need the `HAVING` statement.

```
  select a.*
  from 
    db.table a
  inner join
    (select keyvalue, count(domian_name_cert_no) as rec_count 
     from db.table
     where domian_name_cert_no like '%_1'
     group by keyvalue 
     having rec_count>1) b 
  on a.keyvalue = b.keyvalue;
```

Hope I understood your question.

Comment: Yes. The second query is to list all the records having the keyvalue. For example, In the first query, if I got 10 records have a certain keyvalue, this query to list them for me. I will try your first query.

Comment: When I edited the first statement to be like your suggested one, I got 0 results which should not be the case. I will give you an example of how the stored values look. The columns are stated in my post earlier. Assume the stored values like: 1)a.yahoo.com, a.yahoo.com_1, 222 , 2)a.yahoo.com, a.yahoo.com_2, 333, 3) a.yahoo.com, a.yahoo.com_3, 444, 4) a.msn.com, a.msn.com_1, 222.

Comment: Now since I have the `domian_name_cert_no` content: a.msn.com_1 having the same `keyvalue` to another `domian_name_cert_no` content: a.yahoo.com_1, here I need the counter to be 2 to tell me that this key value occurred twice. In the second query, I need to list all the `domian_name_cert_no` contents in addition to their corressponding `domainname` that shared a certain `keyvalue`, say: 222 in our example.

Comment: @JuryA, I changed to query to reflect the additional information. Let me know if this works for you.